# Rendering composite/SVideo input with GraphEdit (comp./svid. source for crossbar)?

Tags: video-capture, tuner-card, s-video, composite-video

Does anyone know how to form a GraphEdit graph to render composite/SVideo input (especially for a Hauppauge or AIW card)? Google (and Google Images) finds only results focusing on rendering the TV tuner which is already simple enough.

The tv-tuner-in pins connect to the TvTuner/TvAudio source, but nothing seems to be able to connect to the Composite/SVideo pins.

I have looked through the filters and could find no sources to connect to the Composite/SVideo input pins of the crossbar; GraphEdit always complains that they are not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Yay!

It turns out that there is no separate capture source for composite. Instead, you use the *TvTuner* source and connect the pins to the *Tuner In* like you would to render TV (which is just confusing and counterintuitive), but then you set the source to composite in the Crossbar filter.

Here is a screenshot of a graph that renders the composite input. The pins that you would *expect* to be used but are not, are marked in red; the pins you *actually* use that are misleadingly labeled *TV* are marked in orange, and the setting you need to make sure to use is marked in green:

[image: Screenshot of working GraphEdit composite-input graph]